# GoogleScript - setValues() - join elements of an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with the property setValues() in GoogleSheet. Something that seems very simple is bugging me a lot.

I'm trying to create a simple thumbnail of hundreds of classes from a list of references.

My datas look something like below and I have an array with all the unique references (3000,3001)

| Reference | day | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3000 | Mon | 6pm | 8pm |
| 3000 | Tues | 6pm | 8pm |
| 3001 | Mon | 6pm | 8pm |
| 3001 | Tues | 6pm | 8pm |
| 3001 | Wed | 6pm | 8pm |

My function runs like this :

```
function addThumbnails(){
  const result = uniqueReferences.map(uniqueRow =>
    dtA
      .filter(row => row[0] === uniqueRow[0])
      .map((row) => {
           return `${row[1]} : ${row[2]} ${row[3]}`;
       })
          
      );
```

It returns something like :

```
[[Mon: 6pm 8pm, Tue: 6pm 8pm], [Mon: 6pm 8pm, Tue: 6pm 8pm,Wed: 6pm 8pm]]
```

The problem is setValues() doesn't accept arrays of different lengths.

Simply, I would need to join() the elements but somehow I can't do it the right way.

Each arrays inside the array should be 1 element (a string) and occupy only one cell each on the GoogleSheet.

Thank you very much if you find the time to answer,

Cedric

Comment: What is DTA?...

Comment: Sorry, dtA would be the array of the datas I wrote in the table....

Comment: Well you can use the answer that I gave you to load the data into a spreadsheet,  It's pretty simple

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that it actually answers the question which was probably my fault.... I need to be able. I need to go through a filter to find the reference match between two different arrays. One only has unique references, the other has all the datas where sometimes you find the references several times (3000 would be a reference and is found 2 times, 3001 three times). From there my question : how to make each element the same length and use setValues()....

Comment: If you want to use setValues() to load you result into a spreadsheet it must end up as a two dimensional array.  A rectangular array with all rows the same length and my answer is the template for using setValues with array's of that type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I understand these points, I just don't think it answers specifically about my entire question. Another user have answered a solution. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `uniqueReferences = [[3000], [3001]];` and `dtA = [[3000, "Mon",  "6pm",  "8pm"], [3000,  "Tue",  "6pm",  "8pm"], ... ]`

If I got what you need and what the data is, you can try this adjustment

```
const result = uniqueReferences.map(uniqueRow => [
  dtA
    .filter(row => row[0] === uniqueRow[0])
    .map(row => `${row[1]} : ${row[2]} ${row[3]}`).join('; ')
]);
```

The result will be something like

```
[
  [ 'Mon : 6pm 8pm; Tue : 6pm 8pm' ],
  [ 'Mon : 6pm 8pm; Tue : 6pm 8pm; Wed : 6pm 8pm' ]
]
```

Comment: Oh damn, I wasn't putting the join() in the right place, it is working now. Thank you, it was so simple and it really scratched my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh.getRange(startrow,startcol,2DArray.length,2DArray[0].length).setValues(2DArray);
```